# How to update Vue components location from another Vue component ('semi'continuously)

Tags: vue.js, graph, vuejs2, vuex, event-bus

*Tl;dr: To (continuously) update the location of a component from another component, is it performance-wise better to use the Vuex store or an Event-bus?*

**The application**

I'm creating an application in which the user can create Directed Acyclic Graphs. Simply said, there is a canvas, with different `panels` on it. Each panel has multiple `inputs` and multiple `outputs`. The user can connect an output the the input of another panel with a `connector`. The panels are draggable over the canvas, and the panels eventually will be generated dynamically, with different inputs and outputs.

```
____________            ____________
|  PANEL   |            |  PANEL   |
|          |            |          |            
|.input1   |            |.input3   |            
|.input2   |      ,---- |.input4   |            
|          |     /      |          |            
|  output1.| ---'       |  output5.|
|  output2.|            |  output6.|            
|__________|            |__________|
```

(The actual application isn't ascii art, btw)

All objects in the application are in the Vuex Store, the application renders things based on the store:

```
store:{
  panels: { ...paneldetails..., id}[],
  inputs: { ...inputdetails..., id}[],
  outputs: { ...outputdetails..., id}[],
  connections: { ...inputId, outputId..., id}[],
}
```

The user can drag the panels around on the canvas, which means that the connectors are also dragged around on one end at a time. And that is where my question lies: How should I update the `connector`'s location, when a `panel` is moved around?

I thought of two approaches:

**A )** I track the location of each input and output in the store: I just store the x and y along with the ID as soon as they move. I bind one end of each connection to that item in the store, and that's that. That would mean dozens and dozens of store-updates when someone drags a panel around on the screen.

**B )** I send the location of each input and output over an event-bus when it moves, with their ID as key. The connector listens to the ID of the input and output they know, and update when they 'hear' something.

I'm not really sure what the best approach is performance wise, the store might not be suited for continuous updates.

Comment: Not sure why this is opinion based. I have two approaches to a problem, which both will have an impact on performance. I'd like to know which one is the better approach, performance wise.

If you still think it should be closed, please tell me what aspects are too opinionated, so I can try to rephrase or create a better question.

Comment: I think your actual question is something like:  "Will app performance suffer under thousands of positional micro-updates to Vuex?"  (Without mentioning the event bus.)  This is less likely to be perceived as opinion-based, so it might be worth asking.  I think it's a good question, though I'm not sure if it's suited for this site or one of the sister site portals

Comment: Remove "should", "better" and "best". They're trigger words for opinion based. Use "How can I update the..." and Dan's suggestion instead. Once done, ping me and I'll remove my comment. While users may add opinions in their Answers, you'll often get your Question closed for asking about such.